C++ and CUDA name mangling inconsistent
I attempted to compile PyTorch from source but ran into a very strange linking error. After investigating, I discovered that a templated function defined in a C++ file and its declaration in a CUDA file generate two different mangled names.

C++ definition: _ZNK2at10TensorBase14const_data_ptrIdTnNSt9enable_ifIXntsr3stdE10is_const_vIT_EEiE4typeELi0EEEPKS3_v

CUDA declaration: _ZNK2at10TensorBase14const_data_ptrIdTnNSt9enable_ifIXntsr4__T0E10is_const_vIT_EEiE4typeELi0EEEPKS3_v


The 2 names look almost identical except for the bold parts.
When I use llvm-cxxfilt, the 2 mangled names returned the same function name double const* at::TensorBase::const_data_ptr<double, 0>() const
Tools version:

clang: Ubuntu clang version 18.1.8
NVCC: Cuda compilation tools, release 12.6, V12.6.85
NVCC's host compiler: clang 18.1.8 as above

Could you please explain for me:

What are the bold parts in the mangled names? I don't see them in the demangled name.
Why 2 different mangled symbols can result to the same demangled name?


enable_if make me think that it is part of template parameter. and so it might be 2 different overload with different SFINAE/type_traits.

@Jarod42: yes. Exactly. You can view the source code here. The code snippet in question is only few line long. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/aten/src/ATen/core/TensorBase.h#L598

Looks like this is this tool-chain specific mangling, since this tool demangler is unable to parse this mangled names (or you've posted this in wrong way). There should be some a tool shipped with compiler which is able to demangle this.

@MarekR I use llvm-cxxfilt to demangle the symbol names.

nvidia provides a demangler called cu++filt which can full demangle GPU toolchain symbols. The extra parts in the symbol are typically related to GPU side CUDA ABI attributes

@Xellos: the template method is declared in a header file and then included in a CPP file for definition, and included in a CU file to be used. You can see the method here https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/aten/src/ATen/core/TensorBase.h#L598

Here's a demangling hint: strings have length indicated before them in the mangled names. In this case, the part that differs is "3" followed by 3 letters vs "4" followed by 4 letters, so that should be our case.
Next, what sort of string is replaced? We have "std" vs "__T0", so a reasonable guess is a namespace with "E10" indicating ::. The difference would be that one compiler is using std::is_const_v and the other __T0::is_const_v. Indeed, in a minimal example with your function
namespace at {
    class TensorBase {
public:
        template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const_v<T>, int>::type = 0>
        const T * const_data_ptr() const { return nullptr; }
    };
}

int main() {
    at::TensorBase tensorBase;
    tensorBase.const_data_ptr<double>();
}

the template member function corresponds to exactly your C++ symbol. Replacing std::is_const_v by __T0::is_const_v would give your Cuda symbol, and the natural way to end up with this would be headers that redefine parts of std:: in their own namespace, but that's probably not what's going on and a deeper look into nvcc would be required to figure it out. The only references I've found to __T0 in Cuda context were unrelated to this but always involved some compiler specifics - either extra template arguments injected by nvcc or device/host attributes.
Note that this whole deal with including template evaluation in mangled names is quite new, so it's possible that not everything works properly all the time when nvcc is taken into account. For example, with Cuda/NVCC 12.2.140, Clang 18.1.8, I can't reproduce your problem, the code above compiles into your C++ symbol both with nvcc and clang. There must be something more that's nvcc-specific which causes this difference and you might as well file a bug report at NVCC and/or Clang as I don't see a good reason to emit a symbol with 4__T0 no matter what internal magic the compiler's doing.

Thanks for your response. I tried to modified Pytorch's source code and build again. After changing some macro variables which lead to different conditional include, the mangle names are now the same. No idea why that's happens. More over, I changed C++ compiler and CUDA host compiler to clang++ 17, no errors occur. I think, it's compiler (nvcc) bug.

Just one more question: You mentioned that 'including template evaluation in mangled names is quite new.' If I understand correctly, does this mean it’s an ABI-breaking change? In other words, would it be impossible to include a header, compile code with Clang 18, and link it with a library compiled using Clang 17? I thought maintaining ABI stability was a big deal?

@mibu Yes but no way around it, the issue I linked describes what symbol conflict this change resolves. In general, if you need to combine different compilers, go for extern "C" with simple API functions. (Different versions of the same compiler count as different compiler.) Since mangling is up to compiler implementation, this is a recurring problem - you get used to it. At least you can specify the ABI version you want within one build. C++ ABI stability/compatibility is more of an "eh, we try" type of deal.

So now clang/gcc compatibility is no more? I am so used to the idea that whatever compiled with gcc can be linked with clang and vice-versa.

@mibu It's never truly been, there are different ABI versions that you can pick with flags like clang-abi-compat. In practice, you're very unlikely to run into whatever differences appear as actual problems since they try to make the same ABI changes in both compilers to preserve that more-or-less-compatibility. You should still stick to the practical assumption that they're compatible, just keep in mind nothing's perfect.
